# Custom pagination in KendoUI Pager

Tags: pagination, kendo-ui

Is there any way to change the builtin generation of pagination links (e.g. in Grid) within KendoUI?

As far as I've seen, I can only change the template for a single page link. But I'd rather like to change the pagination logic at all. In particular I'm searching for a way to have a digg-style pagination ([1]), which (personally) I see as a more flexible behaviour.

[1] http://blog.localkinegrinds.com/2007/09/06/digg-style-pagination-in-django/

Answer (score 0):

just build your own pager and turn off KendoUI's. You can easily build a paging widget using [Bootstrap.js](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) or [AngularUI](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/pagination)

if you are using the Kendo grid you can easily push in your own skip/take/offset/whatever parameters to your api:

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: function (options) {
                            myService.getFoo({
                                offset: options.data.skip,
                                limit: options.data.pageSize
                            }).then(function (response) {
                                options.success(response.data)
                            });
                        },
```